# configure tidy to escape the unknown xml tags

Tags: xml, tidy, htmltidy, well-formed

I am using tidy to make HTML entered by the user well-formed and i have configured tidy to accept only few html tags. Is there a way i can tell tidy to escape sequence the xml tags that are not known. Example input and the expected output are given below-

Input::
<div>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    <unknown-tag>text in unknown tag</unknown-tag>
<div>

Expected out::
<div>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    **&lt;***unknown-tag***&gt;***text in unknown tag***&lt;***/unknown-tag***&gt;**
<div>

Best Regards,
Keshav

Answer (score 0):

i have also posted this question to tidy forum's and seems there is not way as of now to do this.

BR,
Keshav